# swaggerのYAMLに入力チェック情報を書く方法

Tags: yaml, openapi, swagger

OpenAPI 3.0 で swagger 形式の YAML を作ってるのですが、API の入力チェック情報の書き方で困っています。
どのブロックにどのプロパティを使って書けばいいのか教えていただきたいです。

Comment: api の入力チェック情報とは何を指しているのかもう少し詳しく書いていただくといいと思います。

Comment: 文字数チェックや、日付チェック、英数字チェックなど、それぞれのリクエストパラメータに入力された値が正しい形で入力されているかをチェックするものです。

Answer (score 2):

入力項目の長さの最小値、最大値、入力項目の制限はSchema Objectに記述します。

- https://swagger.io/specification/#schema-object

number / integer / string においてはデータの型定義は`format`フィールドを利用して細分化できます。

- https://swagger.io/specification/#data-types

簡単な例ですが次のようになります。

```yaml
schema:
  type: object
  properties:
    comment:
      type: string
      minimum: 0    # 最小 0文字 
      maximum: 10   # 最大10文字 
    updateAt:
      type: string
      format: date  # RFC3339に則った日付形式
```